# Call Codeigniter controller function in background using COM("WScript.Shell") is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, com

I want to send push notifications in background. For that I want to call php file which will send push notifications in background using COM. Here is my code in which I want to call controller function using COM. But it's not working.

```
  $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
  $oExec = $WshShell->Run("D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php-win.exe -f D:\wamp\www\Project_name\Controller\function", 0, false);
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user guide says running via cli you have to pass everything through index.php and give controller and method. Tools is controller, message is function/method, and parameter is between quotes

```
$ php index.php tools message "hello world"
```

I guess your would look like this, but you have to try.

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php-win.exe -f D:\wamp\www\Project_name\index.php Controller Function", 0, false);
```

Comment: are there any logs? maybe com parameters, or wrong path. I dont know com.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. There is small mistake in my code so previously I got error. But now its fine and working.